# /etc/passwd sql with bash access

Tags: centos, security, users, mysql

I just got a CentOS VPS and was reviewing the passwd file and saw this:

```
mysql:x:498:499:MySQL server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash
```

Is bash necessary for mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell may need to be set in some circumstances, for example if you want to initiate jobs remotely over SSH as the `mysql` user, or through sudo. These aren't common needs. You don't need to have a shell set for cron jobs, `/bin/false` will do fine.

Giving the `mysql` user a shell isn't a security hole on its own. The reason it's frowned upon is that compounded with a misconfiguration of some login service, it might allow someone to obtain a shell as `mysql`. Putting a program that does nothing avoids this — even if an attacker manages to log in as `mysql` that won't do them any good. It's common to use `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin`, but `/bin/true` or any other no-op program would be fine.